# How to setVisible a JinternalFrame in the center of the JdesktopPane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

Actually i wanna show the JinternalFrame in the center of the JDesktopPane and i used this methode as i use it in Jframes but it didn't work :

`Extraction ex=new Extraction();//Extraction is the name of the JintenalFrame 
jDesktopPane1.add(ex);
ex.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    ex.setVisible(true);`

So i am asking if there is another methode so i can display the JinternalFrame in the center of the JdesktoPane.
Thank you

Comment: *"Actually i wanna.."*  I want to correspond with people that will spell all letters of terms like 'want to'.  ***Next!***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `javax.swing.JInternalFrame` lacks the convenient `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` implementation found in `java.awt.Window`, but you can use a similar approach. Just subtract half the width and height of the internal frame from the corresponding center coordinates of the desktop pane. Use the new coordinates in your call to `setLocation()`.

You'll also want to adjust the internal frame's dimensions if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like :

```
JDesktopPane mainPanel;
JInternalFrame jif_test = new JInternalFrame();

public void centerJIF(JInternalFrame jif) {
    Dimension desktopSize = mainPanel.getSize();
    Dimension jInternalFrameSize = jif.getSize();
    int width = (desktopSize.width - jInternalFrameSize.width) / 2;
    int height = (desktopSize.height - jInternalFrameSize.height) / 2;
    jif.setLocation(width, height);
    jif.setVisible(true);
}
```

And

```
centerJIF(jif_test);
```